# Deleting the object twice and causing a memory error

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using C++ lubcurl library. Basically, I want to use curl for GET and POST requests from web server. In this particular case, I am using GET request to retrieve the necessary messages and I spam the server by awaiting any new data with _id field as you can see below (I have deleted unnecessary code which is irrelevant for this error). The error I have is with the double free of the memory. My code is:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

std::size_t callback(const char* in, std::size_t size, std::size_t num, std::string* out){
    const std::size_t totalBytes(size* num);
    out->append(in, totalBytes);
    return totalBytes;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "api_handler");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> ("/move_base_simple/goal", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    /*boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", "http");*/
    const std::string main_url("https://wheelme-protocol-bridge.herokuapp.com/goal/");
    ///
    tf2::Quaternion q;
    int _id = 1;



    while(ros::ok()){
        geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
        std::string url = main_url + std::to_string(_id);
        CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
        // remote url
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        // Using ipv4
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        // waiting time of 10 sec
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        // HTTP redirects if necessary
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        //response info
        long httpCode(0);
        std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

        // Hook up a container type for CURL:
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());

        // Cleaning the HTTP and catching the response:
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        if (httpCode=200){
            ROS_INFO("Got successful response");
            Json::Value jsonData;
            Json::Reader jsonReader;
            if (jsonReader.parse(*httpData.get(), jsonData)){
                ROS_INFO("Parsed JSON data");
                const double x(jsonData["position"]["x"].asDouble());
                    // Doing some stuf with JSON data

            }
            else{
                ROS_INFO("Could not parse json response");
            }
        }
        else{
            ROS_INFO("No new goal");
        }


        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I use ROS here but this is also irrelevant, as the problem here is with my incorrect usage of libcurl. The imporant thing, however, is while(ros::ok()), which is an infinite loop and runs again and again until the master pc is on. So I do understand that the problem is my double deletion (free) of lubcurl object curl but I do not understand where I free curl twice? As I redeclare a new object every time.

Comment: Off topic but why do you dynamically allocate a `std::string`?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I don't understand the need for the `std::unique_ptr<std::string>`. Since you're making a *synchronous* call, you can just have a scoped `std::string str;` and pass it's address: `&str`, as your write-data user param..

Comment: And if it weren't a synchronous call then it would be broken because the smart pointer would still go out of scope, taking the string with it

Comment: FWIW though I can't see the problem with your Curl usage.

Comment: I don't see a curl problem either. You said, "*I have deleted unnecessary code which is irrelevant for this error"* - that's fine, so long as what is posted, and *only* what is posted, still produces the error. From a curl-perspective, I don't see a problem, so something else is amiss.

Comment: I cannot find any *free* in your code. That is good! Using *new*  you should match it with *delete*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What would you suggest regarding the dynamic allocation?

Comment: @peakpeak Isn't curl_easy_cleanup(curl); mean for freeing?

Comment: Yeah it is. Presumably that line triggers the problem but your usage looks right. Can you verify for us that this exact snippet causes it?